# I need a dynamic content in the same page on different button clicks

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The three image buttons on click should display different content.

The javascript I am using to activate `div` display on client click is:

```
function showfirstdiv()
{
    document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";    
}

function showseconddiv()
{
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";  
}

function showthirddiv()
{
    document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";          
}
```

And the div are:

```
<div id="1" style="display:none">Internal Holiday Entry</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none">Weekend Holiday Entry</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none">National Holiday Entry</div>
```

The first button is:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="showfirstdiv()"/>
```

Comment: Do you want that button you click to show the image in sequence `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1...` ?

Comment: No. Like when I click the first button the first div will be visible, then when second button is clicked the second div and the first will be hidden will be shown and so on

Comment: Then you have to hide the other 2 images when you show one.

Comment: They are the images. Only the page content under the image buttons to change on click

Comment: Its not working @fuyushimoya

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you just need to hide the other divs you dont want to display.

Here is a working example : https://jsfiddle.net/6g63vb79/

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="showHolidayEntry(1)"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" OnClientClick="showHolidayEntry(2)"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" OnClientClick="showHolidayEntry(3)"/>
<div id="1" class="holiday-entry" style="display:none">Internal Holiday Entry</div>
<div id="2" class="holiday-entry" style="display:none">Weekend Holiday Entry</div>
<div id="3" class="holiday-entry" style="display:none">National Holiday Entry</div>
```

Javascript

```
this.showHolidayEntry = function (id) {
    var entries = document.getElementsByClassName('holiday-entry');

    for(var i = 0, entry; entry = entries[i]; i++) {
        entry.style.display = entry.id == id ? '' : 'none';
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button is causing a postback. You just have to change this line :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="showfirstdiv(); return false;"/>
```